# Regular Expressions misunderstanding or just broken implementation?

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, c++11

I tried a very simple use of `regex_search` and can not understand why I do not get a match:

Alas, the gcc-C++0x-implementations 4.5 does not seem to be working, I get a link error [here](http://ideone.com/LY7hc).

But here is my gcc-4.7.0 try, quite straightforward:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    regex rxWorld("world");
    const string text = "hello world!";
    const auto t0 = text.cbegin();
    smatch match;
    const bool ok = regex_search(text, match, rxWorld);
    /* ... */
}
```

I think I should get `ok==true` *and* something in `match` as well. I reduced the example to a very simple regex for this. I tried slightly more complicated first.

But by printing code at `/* ... */` says otherwise:

```
  cout << "  text:'" << text
       << "' ok:" << ok
       << " size:" << match.size();
  cout << " pos:" << match.position()
       << " len:"<< match.length();
  for(const auto& sub : match) {
      cout << " ["<<(sub.first-t0)<<".."<<(sub.second-t0)
           << ":"<<sub.matched
           << "'"<<sub.str()
           << "']";
  }
  cout << endl;
```

The output is:

```
$ ./regex-search-01.x
text:'hello world!' ok:0 size:0 pos:-1 len:0
```

*Update: I also tried `regex_search(t0, text.cend(), match, rxWorld)` and `const char* text`, no change.*
`

**Is my understanding of `regex_search` wrong?** I am completely baffled. Or is it just the gcc?

Comment: Have not used the new regexp stuff myself, but based on a quick google, you are using regex_match with the wrong parameters.  http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_regex.html

Comment: Yes, I used that tutorial to hone my knowledge, too. The functions have a bunch of overloads. Mine with a `string` should work as well, but maybe I should try with iterators, too. Wait... no, no change.

Comment: Hmmm.....  I figured there might be overloads.  Which makes sense since it's compiling.  Hmmm....

Comment: I tried this with Boost 1.47 and GCC 4.6.1 and got, `text:'hello world!' ok:1 size:1 pos:6 len:5 [6..11:1'world']`.

Comment: @kerrek: Thanks! I suspect gcc, then. Make an answer of your finding, if you like.

Comment: I tried this with MSVC++ 2010 and the included `tr1::regex`. It produced the same output that Kerrek SB shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the [C++-0x status of libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x) the regex support is incomplete.
In particular match_results are not finished.  Iterators are not even started.

Volunteers are welcome ;-)

[EDIT] [As of gcc-4.9][2](http://gcc.gnu.org/)  will be fully supported.