# C++11 std::regex_match returning extra character

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, c++11, gnu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is gcc4.7 buggy about regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions)

I followed the example on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/regex/regex_match/ and compiled on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit with g++ version 4.6.3

The following is my output:

```
string literal matched
string object matched
range matched
string literal with 3 matches
string object with 3 matches
range with 3 matches
the matches were: [subject] [sub] [bject]
```

While the sample output is:

```
string literal matched
string object matched
range matched
string literal with 3 matches
string object with 3 matches
range with 3 matches
the matches were: [subject] [sub] [ject]
```

Notice that on my machine **[bject]** is extracted which is not right. Any ideas?

Comment: indeed ... http://liveworkspace.org/code/05747d2336f0fcd071aba84ba3fd13fb

Comment: Does it mean that it's a bug of std:regex?

Comment: I can confirm this result (same environment).

Comment: seems like it. The .net regex works correctly. gotta check out other implementations

Comment: the boost version works as in the reference: http://liveworkspace.org/code/c3a13f6bb14f9cdb7b605d737710de8b

Comment: G++ 4.6.3 seems still have some problems with regex of C++11. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011

Comment: std::regex vc++11 delivers the expected results.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [gcc implementation status (ver 4.6.3)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011) the regex library is not yet completely implemented. It throws no errors and provides no warnings. Which is unpleasant, indeed.

However, others have observed this before, with more recent versions as well:

- [Is this C++11 regex error me or the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8060025/1025391)
- [Difference between regex_match and regex_search?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11628047/1025391)
- [Is gcc 4.8 or earlier buggy about regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12530406/1025391)
- [Regular Expressions misunderstanding or just broken implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7696063/1025391)

The common suggestion is to further use [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) or to give a try to another compiler.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/1025391) for some further reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the example to:

```
std::string s("subject");
std::regex e("(sub)(.*)");
std::smatch sm;
std::regex_match(s, sm, e);
```

even more interesting:

```
std::string s("subject");
std::regex e("(sub)(ject)");
std::smatch sm;
std::regex_match(s, sm, e);
```

So, this looks like a bug in the GNU implementation.

Comment: it's just not yet implemented completely.

Comment: @moooeeeep make that correctly ;-)

Comment: incomplete implies incorrect.